# JSON Headers is missing in Azure Data Factory (v2)

Tags: json, azure, cloud, azure-data-factory

In the pipeline, I used copy data activity to fetch data from REST API into a .txt file

This is the preview of source data:
[image]

However after running the pipeline, I received the following output:
[image]

Now where is the column header? Is there something that I might have missed in configuring during creating the copy data activity?

EDIT: Here's the sink configuration:
[image]

Comment: Can you share what you are using as a sink? Where are you storing the .txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably missed the option "First row as header" when configuring the sink dataset. Check that you have this enabled in the sink dataset of your copy activity:

[image: First row as header]

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Somehow I forgot to tick this one back. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help!! :)

Comment: Is there any way to separate the headers into multiple columns? At this moment everything goes into one single column

Comment: Mmm thats weird, have you tried going into the schema tab and clicked Import Schema?

Comment: Not yet. As I am copying the data from REST endpoint into csv, which schema do I need to import?